# structure of java projects and how to open it

Tags: java, eclipse, directory, jgrasp, jcreator

I have downloaded a folder with current structure:

.settings (folder)

.src (folder)

.classpath (file)

.project (file)

input.txt

So basically in the .src folder there is a java file that I would like to launch and it should read the input.txt file. I was trying to just open and launch that java file but it doesn't do the job it should do. Therefore I assume that this is so called java project and I should open it in some special way to make it run but the question is how I should open (or import) it?

Answer (score 3):

This particular project seems to be using [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) configuration files to provide the build structure. It would be best to import it in Eclipse and build it from there. You can also try other tools that support Eclipse project format e.g. [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

Answer (score 1):

It seems You have eclipse project(it has .project file). You can look into eclipse documentation on how to import eclipse project. http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-importproject.htm